# how can i change the text of the button without clicked in the listview delegate?

Tags: qml

I write a listview to show some information, when i clicked the button in the `pDelegate`, the text on the button will change to "Added", now i want to save the model's data, when i restart the program, such "Added" items will autoshow "Added",but i can't realize this. when i mark a variable to the button text,all the button text will show "Added",i just want the specific item that matched the saved data to show "Added", Please help me, thanks!!!

```
ListModel{
        id:pModel
    }

    ListView{
        id:pView
        anchors.fill:parent
        model:pModel
        delegate:pDelegate
        anchors.margins: 15
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        onAddChanged: {
            console.log("added");
            m_added = false;
        }
    }

Component{
        id:pDelegate

        Rectangle{
            id:printerItem
            width:parent.width
            height:60
            Text{
                id:printerName
                text:prname
                font.pixelSize: 18
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: pImg.width
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Component{
                id:btnStyle3
                ButtonStyle{
                    background: Rectangle{
                        width:control.width
                        height:control.height
                        color:printerItem.color
                    }
                    label:Text{
                        text:qsTr("Added")
                        font.pixelSize: 18
                        anchors.fill: parent

                    }
                }
            }


            MouseArea{
                id:itemMouseArea
                hoverEnabled: true
                anchors.fill: parent
                onHoveredChanged: {
                    pView.currentIndex = index;
                }
                onEntered: {
                    printerItem.color = "#f5f5f5";
                }
                onExited: {
                    printerItem.color = "white";
                }
            }

            Button{
                id:btnAdd
                width:60
                height: 40
                anchors.right: printerItem.right
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                style:ButtonStyle{
                    id:btnAddStyle
                    background: Rectangle{
                        width:control.width
                        height:control.height
                        color: printerItem.color
                    }
                    label:Text{
                        id:btnText
                        color:control.hovered?"#0087ff":"black"
                        text:control.pressed?qsTr("Added"):qsTr("Add")
                        font.pixelSize: 18
                        anchors.fill: parent
                    }
                }

                onClicked: {
                    busyIndicator.visible = true;
                    busyIndicator.running = true;
                      clienter.setDefaultPrinter(printerName.text,index);
                    btnAdd.style = btnStyle3;
                    m_added = true;
                }


                Connections{
                    target:printerlist
                    onAddedChanged:{
                        console.log("onAddedChanged");
                    }
                }

                    Connections{
                        target: printerlist
                        onStopSpinner:{
                            timer.start();
                        }
                    }


                }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just remove unnecessary items like `Image`s and `BusyIndicator` etc.

Comment: AFAIK QML has no support for writing to the disk. You need to implement a model in C++, that does the persistence stuff for you.

Comment: yes,i save the data( string) in c++ ,and use a javascript global varible to receive the string , the string is a item name list,that i will use to show on the listelement , then i will use the model to append the element .  but when the button text have been displayed ,how can i change the button text i want to change in the delegate, i can't use the button id to access the button text, the only way to change the button text is to click the button , so how to change it not to click button??

Comment: There is `Settings` type, also there is possibility to do that through `C++` of cource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finally,i add a model role 
pModel.append({"prname":pname[i],"prstate": qsTr(Jsclient.pstate)});
```

and you can use the workerscript to

```
sendmessage({"prname":pname[i],"prstate": qsTr(Jsclient.pstate)})
```

to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your buttons `Text` element property `text` from

```
text:control.pressed?qsTr("Added"):qsTr("Add")
```

to

```
text: m_added ? qsTr("Added") : qsTr("Add")
```

this will bind your buttons text value to value of `m_added`.

Comment: i have tried,but when m_added changed,all the buttons text will change, i just want one button that i have saved result that change.

Comment: @poolooloowu , i see, but looks like your buttons get value of some variable instead of model data role. Maybe try to remove `m_added = false` from `ListView.onAddChanged`? It looks like you are trying to set value of model role in place where you can't access model data and accidentally declare new variable.

Comment: finally,i add a model role  pModel.append({"prname":pname[i],"prstate": qsTr(Jsclient.pstate)});

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your `m_adde` is defined, but it looks like a single property or JavaScript variable not a role provided by your model.

As a separate value needs to be associated with each entry in the model, the easiest option is to make "added" another bit of information provided by the model.

That way each delegate has its own state and that state can be saved and loaded as part of the model data.