# why qml listmodel sync failed when in the worker thread,and how to solve it?

Tags: qml

[how can i change the text of the button without clicked in the listview delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521956/how-can-i-change-the-text-of-the-button-without-clicked-in-the-listview-delegate/42690223?noredirect=1#comment72503948_42690223)

when i solved the question above,there is a new question.i can't use the worker to sync the model,but when i use sync not in the worker,although it has some error occured from qtcreator,but it works to sync the data role in the model ,and often, sync will fail.

**dataloader.js:**

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(msg) {
         msg.model.sync();
 }
```

**PrinterList.qml:**

```
WorkerScript{
        id:worker
        source:"dataloader.js"
    }

function cmpPname(prnName)
    {
        console.log("cmpPname");
        var tmpName = prnName.replace(/_/g," ");
        console.log("tmpName=",tmpName);
        var pname = new Array;
        pname= Jsclient.g_str.split(',');
        tmpName = tmpName.split(',');
        console.log("pModel.count=",pModel.count);
        for(var i = 0;i < pname.length;i++){
            if(tmpName == pname[i]){
                console.log("pname[%1]=".arg(i),pname[i]);
                Jsclient.pstate = "Added";
                pModel.setProperty(i,"prstate",qsTr(Jsclient.pstate));
//                pModel.get(2).prstate = qsTr(Jsclient.pstate);
                sync();  **//this works!!but often failed too.**
            }else{
                Jsclient.pstate = "Add";
                pModel.setProperty(i,"prstate",qsTr(Jsclient.pstate));
            }
            worker.sendMessage({"model":pModel});  **//this failed,why?**
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as qt help doc said:sync()
Writes any unsaved changes to the list model after it has been modified from a worker script.      but why i sync the listmodel would failed?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,i solved the question.
dataloader.js:

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.index,msg.prstate);
    msg.model.setProperty(msg.index,"prstate",msg.prstate);

    msg.model.sync();
 }
```

list.qml:

```
       worker.sendMessage({"index":i,"prstate":qsTr("Added"),"model":pModel});
```